# ionic 5 push notifications One signal ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Tags: ionic-framework

He tried to follow the docs, but I don´t know that I have done.

Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain an `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

[Learn more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Apple Developer Guidelines, the generated Info.plist file should contain a proper message for the user that tells why your app needs the data.

In your config.xml file, add the following lines outside of  tag

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>Need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```